# Power Bi Conditional Formatting

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, conditional-formatting

In Power Bi i am using the Conditional formatting where Red is 0-89 Yellow 90-94 Green 95-100
This is only work on certain cells in a column and not them all
I have attached 2 photos one with the result and one with the format
[[Result Image and Format image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icnuv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rWdv.png)

I have changed the format around and changes the order would i need to average the percentages or sum?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Percent` in the Conditional Formating drop-down in the rules, it means if the value is in that percent-range of the results in the visual. Change it to `Number` and then ensure you enter the values as decimal. For example:

[image]